# Customize the hyperlink

Tags: docusignapi

Thanks for the tip on how to [Create An Active Hyperlink From a Datafield](http://community.docusign.com/t5/Tips-Tricks/DocuSign-Quick-Tip-Create-An-Active-Hyperlink-From-a-Datafield/td-p/10511). Can the link style be customized? I do not wish to have a border and would like to change its font  to match rest of my document.

Not sure if the community site is still active. So posting here.

Thanks in advance.
Naresh

Comment: Are you programatically creating the link with the DocuSign API, or just creating it manually via the DocuSign web console UI? This (stackoverflow) forum is for API questions...the "Community" forum (on the DocuSign website) is for web console / features & functionality questions.

Comment: I am adding a link via SOAP API. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the SOAP API, you can specify the font style, color, and size of text within a data field by using the following properties within the `Tab` element in the API Request:

```
<Tab>
    ...
     <Font>Arial or ArialNarrow or Calibri or CourierNew or Garamond or Georgia or Helvetica or LucidaConsole or Tahoma or TimesNewRoman or Trebuchet or Verdana</Font> 
     <FontColor>Black or BrightBlue or BrightRed or DarkRed or DarkGreen or Gold or Green or NavyBlue or Purple or White</FontColor> 
     <FontSize>Size7 or Size8 or Size9 or Size10 or Size11 or Size12 or Size14 or Size16 or Size18 or Size20 or Size22 or Size24 or Size26 or Size28 or Size36 or Size48 or Size72</FontSize>
    ...
</Tab>
```

For more information about these properties, see the DocuSign SOAP API guide (http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/DocuSignAPI_Guide.pdf).

As specified in the Community forum (http://community.docusign.com/t5/Templates-and-Powerforms/Hyperlink-in-contract/td-p/25837), it's not currently possible to remove the border around the hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

If using the DocuSign Web Console, as Kim has mentioned you should be using DocuSign's internal community for such questions, but you can simply edit the font settings of the data field to match your document settings.

If sending through the API, which is what the DocuSignAPI tag on Stack Overflow is used for (i.e. api and development questions), then you can set the font settings of your datafield through an API call.  In the DocuSign REST API, data fields are called "textTabs" and the three that related to font settings are:

```
"font": "arial",
"fontColor": "black",
"fontSize": "size12",
```

The full body of a **textTab** has the following potential properties that you can include:

```
"textTabs": [{
  "anchorString": null,
  "anchorXOffset": null,
  "anchorYOffset": null,
  "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": null,
  "anchorUnits": null,
  "conditionalParentLabel": null,
  "conditionalParentValue": null,
  "documentId": "1",
  "pageNumber": "1",
  "recipientId": "1",
  "templateLocked": false,
  "templateRequired": false,
  "xPosition": "24",
  "yPosition": "153",
  "bold": false,
  "font": "arial",
  "fontColor": null,
  "fontSize": null,
  "italic": false,
  "tabLabel": "Data Field 13",
  "underline": false,
  "concealValueOnDocument": false,
  "disableAutoSize": false,
  "locked": false,
  "name": "Text",
  "required": true,
  "value": "",
  "width": 42,
  "mergeFieldXml": "",
  "requireInitialOnSharedChange": false,
  "shared": false,
  "validationMessage": "",
  "validationPattern": "",
  "height": 11,
  "isPaymentAmount": false
}]
```

http://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm